# Fancybox on page load error

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

This is driving me crazy

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'onCleanup'
```

Here's my header code:

```
<head id="ctl00_Head1"><title>

    Artworking

</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css?v=1" />    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jgrowl.css?v=1" />    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.4.4.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jgrowl.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/artworkDesigner.css?v=1" />      
    <link href="js/uploadify-2.1.4/uploadify.css?v=1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/uploadify-2.1.4/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/uploadify-2.1.4/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css?v=1" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        // Load everything up    
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $.fancybox(    
            '<h2>Hi!</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque</p>',    
            {    
                'autoDimensions'    : false,    
                'width'                 : 350,    
                'height'                : 'auto',    
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',    
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'   
            }    
        );

        });          
    </script>
</head>
```

I've moved the fancy folder from root to `root/js` so it exists in `/js/fancybox/`.  I've checked the references to the JS/CSS files, and they are all linked fine, I've also changed the relevant links in the CSS file to reference js/, IE

```
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-n { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_n.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
```

Now equals

```
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-n { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='js/fancybox/fancy_shadow_n.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
```

But no luck :0

Comment: Bizzare, even though I cleared cache etc and hard refreshed many times it's just working now after not changing anything.

Comment: Nope, back to same error, I'm not changing ANYTHING in the code anywhere, it seems to intermitantly work.  I've snipped out some JS after the fancy box code for readability, sounds like some sort of timing condition that's messing this up?

Comment: When I click another link, then press back to that page in my browser, it works fine 100% of the time, anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Solved, moving the CSS definition above the JS includes solves this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will solve the problem, but could you try moving the declaration of the mousewheel script after the one for the fancybox script? i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
```

Let me know if this works. Otherwise, have you tried running it under Firefox with the Firebug debugger. You can set it to breakpoint on errors and do some inspection of the code and the current state of variables at this point?

Comment: Thanks neil, you were along the right lines, but the CSS definition needs to be loaded before the JS.